# Вывод ячеек с совпадениями из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени. Есть таблица с большим количеством полей и столбцов. Мне нужно, что бы при поиске на страницу выводилась именно та ячейка, где было найдено совпадение.
Предположим, ввожу в поиске "министр" и php мне выводит запись "Министр иностранных дел поехал туда-то", а ниже следующие ячейки с совпадениями.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, что Вы пробовали сделать? Как пробовали искать и выводить данные?

Comment: Я сначала выявлял значения всех столбцов через
    `$cols = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW columns FROM progs');`
    
Затем, в цикле искал совпадения, перебирая все поля
`while ($field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cols)) {
     if ((isset($search))) {
      $search_name = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM progs WHERE " . $field["Field"] . " LIKE '%$search%'");`

Comment: Но в этом случае я могу вывести только столбец, который задам сам, например, `$row['opisanie']`. А мне нужна именно ячейка с совпадением.

Comment: Мне нужны сами записи. В MySQL запросе переменная `$field["Field"]` как раз и перебирает все существующие столбцы по циклу. я это сделал, дабы не вводить их вручную, потому что их в будущем, возможно, будет много. Я не могу понять как дальше все это реализовать.

Comment: Предположим, я отправил запрос `"SELECT * FROM progs WHERE 'opisanie' LIKE '%$search%' OR 'desc' LIKE '%$search%'"`. Затем я присваиваю этот массив переменной в PHP. Дальше я не могу понять как сделать вывод именно той записи, где совпадение было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стройте примерно такой запрос сразу со всеми столбцами:

```
SELECT (opisanie LIKE '%$search%') as in_opisanie,
       (desc LIKE '%$search%')     as in_desc,
       P.*
  FROM progs P 
 WHERE opisanie LIKE '%$search%'
    OR desc LIKE '%$search%'
```

По получении строки пробегаете по всем ее полям foreach, если поле in_X равно 1  - значит в поле X было совпадение и его можно выводить.

А вообще стоит задуматься о структуре БД. Такой вариант мягко говоря тормозной. Возможно имеет смысл задействовать полнотектовый поиск или, если по каким то причинам это не подходит, делать индексную таблицу в виде:

```
id,
id_записи_основной_таблицы,
id_столбца,
слово или id_слова
```

Если поиск по отдельным словам приемлим, сделать словарь в котором каждому уникальному слову будет дан id. Тогда при поиске можно будет искать не like, а строгим равенством и после уже по id найденных слов подбирать записи основной таблицы. Заодно будете сразу знать в каких колонках найдено. И все это сможет работать по индексам, что на большом объеме данных будет в разы быстрее, чем `like '%X%'` да еще и по всем полям.